# Heroku Error:symbol lookup error: /app/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: undefined symbol: pango_fc_font_map_set_default_substitute

Tags: node.js, heroku, canvas, puppeteer

I Don't know why I getting this error on Heroku puppeteer and canvas app
[image: Error]

I using this puppeteer Build pack:https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack

Puppeteer version:`^13.5.2`

[canvas](https://npmjs.org/canvas) version : `^2.9.0`